# HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) not adaptive on Android 4?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I've been trying to stream video to Android devices using HLS, which is officially supported since HoneyComb. The problem is, when I use the Apple HLS test stream there seems to be no adaptivity. When I have a good connection i get a proper stream in high quality, but when I use 3G i get the same quality and streaming lags. I've been using the standard Android classes for this:

```
String Url = AppleUrl = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8";
MediaController mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vid);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(Url);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.start();
    }
});
```

When using VLC I get the same result, has anybody tested if Android really supports the adaptivity of HLS streaming?

**UPDATE**

Updated the stream URL to the multi track m3u8 playlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it turns out Android does support HLS streaming but the adaptive bit rate switching part is left out. As soon as the connection gets better or worse and a different video track is chosen the stream freezes and soon after that the app crashes.

Comment: On Android 4.4.2, using [this HLS stream](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8), the  movie restarts at the beginning when choosing alternate track.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the URL to the playlist is for a specific bitrate and it's not possible to do adaptive streaming unless the Android client knows about the alternate renditions.

You need to set a different URL to the `VideoView`. Try this one which contains multiple bitrates: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8